# What is the best way to do "replace-if"?

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I'm thinking of a function that can replace the value `x` with `z` when `x` is `y`, and do nothing otherwise, that is:

```
\x -> if x == y then z else x
```

It's only used once in my program and it's in the middle of a function chain so I don't want to define it as a named function and I think the lambda expression looks unnecessarily verbose. Instead, I'm trying to compose it from other functions. However, so far I have only come up with this cryptic (and cring-y) one:

```
(ap . flip . bool id $ const z) (== y)
```

Are there better point-free forms for such a simple function?

Comment: I think there's nothing really better than the first pointful version.

Comment: @chi: Yeah maybe. But I'm really not satisfied by `my . awesome . (\x -> if x == y then z else x) . function . chain $ val`. :P

Comment: Why not just define it in a ```where``` clause?

Comment: An aside: quite a few people dislike if-then-else expressions, some to the point of wanting to see them removed from the language for being superfluous special syntax. Personally, however, I think they are just fine and have their place -- they are compact, can be inserted pretty much anywhere and, unlike things like `bool`, never leave you wondering wbout the order of the arguments.

Comment: I believe @duplode is referring to [this](https://github.com/strake/rfcs/blob/if/texts/0000-no-if-then-else.rst) RFC and its subsequent [discussion](https://github.com/haskell/rfcs/pull/10).

Comment: @Alec That's what I had in mind, indeed (it is the latest instance that I happened to see of a recurring complaint).

Comment: If `y` is a constant, say `42`, you can do `(\case 42 -> z; x -> x)` with `LambdaCase`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of anything very readable.  Shortest I can get is

```
bool z <*> (/= y)
```

Further silly ways:

```
execState (gets (==y) >>= flip when (put z))

fromMaybe <*> flip lookup [(y, z)]
```

Comment: I feel `bool z <*> (/= y)` is the least bad choice amongst these answers.

Answer (score 4):

I don't approve of this very much, but a quick [Hayoo search](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=a+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+Bool%29+-%3E+a+-%3E+a) led me to the [`(?|)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-easy-0.7.0/docs/Data-Easy.html#v:-63--124-) operator in the [`data-easy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-easy) package. This package is full of such functions (with a bunch of disclaimers about "non-idiomatic haskell"). Looks like you could have

```
\x -> if x == y then z else x  -- the cluttered Haskell form

\x -> x ?| (/= y) $ z          -- the "Pythonic" form

(?| (/= y)) z                  -- Haskell-sections-galore of the "Pythonic" form
```

Jokes aside, there is also the much more reasonable [`fromBoolC`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-easy-0.7.0/docs/Data-Easy.html#v:fromBoolC) that you will probably like:

```
fromBoolC z (/= y)
```

Comment: Straight from the docs of `Data.Easy`: "Note: This is probably not considered good practice. Use the standard if-then-else instead, its almost always clearer. You have been warned." Indeed, why should I look up an uncommon function when a straightforward basic readable alternative exists?

Answer (score 4):

From [`lens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens):

```
import Control.Lens

f = (^. non z) . (non y # ) -- for some z and y
```

The `if then else` version is definitely better though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Python trick of replacing a case statement with a lookup.

```
import Data.Map

\x -> findWithDefault x x (singleton y z)
```

which according to pointfree.io can be reduced to

```
flip (join findWithDefault) (singleton y z)
```

It's not exactly clear, but at the same time it separates the functional parts from the arguments. `flip (join findWithDefault)` does what you want, and `singleton y z` is a DSL-like way of specifying the exception. Stick a `idExcept = flip (join findWithDefault)` and `exception = singleton` earlier in your code, and your chain is almost readable.

```
my . awesome . (idExcept (exception y z)) . function . chain $ val
```